# Get whether a comment is a parent or not in Disqus in a Django Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, disqus

I am using Disqus for comments on my django site. I am trying to send mails to users when someone comments on their posts. SO i need the following information:

1. Post Author
2. Post URL
3. Comment Author
4. Comment parent

I have been able to get the first 3 by:

```
this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function(comment) { 
            var u = "{{ user.username }}";  
            alert(u);
            alert("{{question.user}}");
            alert(getCurrentURL());//This function returns the current URL
            //Now we can call a server side function with all the data which will send the mails
        }];
```

However, i am not able to track if that comment is a parent comment or not. If it is a parent comment, then i don't need any extra information but if that comment is a reply to some other comment then i need that parent comment user as well so that i can send mail to them as well. Any idea how it can be done, i.e., getting the information of the parent comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way to retrieve info about a parent's post that I see possible is by making an AJAX call to the Disqus API (the callback does not have access to enough information to determine anything else about the current post, besides it's ID and text).

This is what I would do:

1. Register a new application at https://disqus.com/api/applications/. Make sure it's Domain is set to allow the domain the AJAX request will come from.
2. Make an AJAX request to the [getContext](https://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/getContext/) API endpoint Disqus offers. It will provide a list of all the parents of the current post (the current post being the last element of the array, it's parent on n-1, and so forth), along with information about the author's Disqus account *(note: Disqus does not make email addresses public, I'm assuming you already can handle mapping a Disqus account to it's email address based on the same data source you use for retrieving the current author's email)*.

This is what the `onNewComment` callback would look like:

```
this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function(comment) { 
   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: 'https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/getContext.json',
      data: { 
              post:  comment.id, 
              api_key: '{{ APPLICATION PUBLIC KEY HERE }}'
      }, 
      success: function(data){ 
          console.log(data.response);
      }
   })
}];
```